# How to optimize Matrix initialization and transposition to run faster using C

Tags: c, matrix, initialization, transpose

The dimension of this matrix is 40000*40000. I was supposed to consider spatial and temporal locality for program but I have no idea to optimize this code. It cost about 50+ seconds in my computer which is not acceptable for our group.The size of block is 500 now. Could someone help me to improve this code?

```
void      InitializeMatrixRowwise(){
    int i,j,ii,jj;
    double x;
    x = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i < DIMENSION; i += BLOCKSIZE)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < DIMENSION; j += BLOCKSIZE)
        {
            for (ii = i; ii < i+BLOCKSIZE && ii < DIMENSION; ii++)
            {
                for (jj = j; jj < j+BLOCKSIZE && jj < DIMENSION; jj++)
                {
                    if (ii >= jj)
                    {
                        Matrix[ii][jj] = x++;
                    }
                    else
                        Matrix[ii][jj] = 1.0;
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }




void        TransposeMatrixRowwise(){
int column,row,i,j;
double temp;
for (row = 0; row < DIMENSION; row += BLOCKSIZE)
{
    for (column = 0; column < DIMENSION; column += BLOCKSIZE)
    {
        for (i = row; i < row + BLOCKSIZE && i < DIMENSION; i++)
        {
            for (j = column; j < column + BLOCKSIZE && j < DIMENSION; j++)
            {
                if (i > j)
                {
                    temp = Matrix[i][j];
                    Matrix[i][j] = Matrix[j][i];
                    Matrix[j][i] = temp;
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
 }
```

Comment: What compiler and flags are you using, a possible first step could be try some compiler-based optimizations, another thing you could look at is to make sure the integers are stored in registers rather than in cache / memory, possibly using inline asm

Comment: Do you have to do this 50+ seconds initialization only once, or several time during a session?

Comment: The 40k x 40k matrix uses about 12.8 GiB if the elements are `double`, or about half that if they're `float`.  That is big; it takes time to initialize that much data, even assuming that you have enough physical RAM to have it all in memory at once.

Comment: When I run a timing test on your code with a timing harness at 40k x 40k with block size 500 x 500 — on a 2016 MacBook Pro with 16 GiB 2133 MHz LPDDR3 RAM and 2.7 GHz Intel Core i7 — it took `Matrix (40000x40000, blocks 500x500)` / `Initialization: 10.597134` / `Transposition: 22.087354`, or just under 33 seconds, which is entirely comparable with what you measured.  The code working in block-size subunits has the potential to cause less sequential access to memory, but getting the same result by other mechanisms is definitely not so easy.  I tried one way, but it produced different resuts.

Comment: Actually the elements have to be double in terms of requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Your transpose function seems like it might be more complex than necessary and therefore perhaps slower than necessary.  However, I created two versions of the code with timing inserted on the 'full size' (40k x 40k array, with 500 x 500 blocks), one using your transpose function and one using this much simpler algorithm:

```
static void TransposeMatrixRowwise(void)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < DIMENSION; row++)
    {
        for (int col = row + 1; col < DIMENSION; col++)
        {
            double temp = Matrix[row][col];
            Matrix[row][col] = Matrix[col][row];
            Matrix[col][row] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

This looks much simpler; it has only two nested loops instead of four, but the timing turns out to be dramatically worse — 31.5s vs 14.7s.

```
# Simple transpose
# Count    = 7
# Sum(x1)  =  220.87
# Sum(x2)  = 6979.00
# Mean     =   31.55
# Std Dev  =    1.27 (sample)
# Variance =    1.61 (sample)
# Min      =   30.41
# Max      =   33.54

# Complex transpose
# Count    = 7
# Sum(x1)  =  102.81
# Sum(x2)  = 1514.00
# Mean     =   14.69
# Std Dev  =    0.82 (sample)
# Variance =    0.68 (sample)
# Min      =   13.59
# Max      =   16.21
```

The reason for the performance difference is almost certainly due to locality of reference.  The more complex algorithm is working with two separate blocks of memory at a time, whereas the simpler algorithm is ranging over far more memory, leading to many more page misses, and the slower performance.

Thus, while you might be able to tune the transpose algorithm using different block sizes (it needn't be the same block size as was used to generate the matrices), there is little doubt based on these measurements
that the more complex algorithm is more efficient.

I also did a check at 1/10th scale — 4k x 4k matrix, 50 x 50 block size — to ensure that the output from the transposition was the same (about 152 MiB of text).  I didn't save the data at full scale with more than 100 times as much data.  The times at 1/10th scale were dramatically better — less than 1/100th time — for both versions at the 1/10th scale:

```
< Initialization: 0.068667
< Transposition: 0.063927
---
> Initialization: 0.081022
> Transposition: 0.039169
4005c4005
< Print transposition: 3.901960
---
> Print transposition: 4.040136
```

JFTR: Testing on a 2016 MacBook Pro running macOS High Sierra 10.13.1 with 2.7 GHz Intel Core i7 CPU and 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3 RAM.  The compiler was GCC 7.2.0 (home-built).  There was a browser running (but mostly inactive) and music playing in the background, so the machine wasn't idle, but I don't think those will dramatically affect the numbers.

Comment: Yeah,I think the key to improve is locality of reference.But I've changed the code from the version with simpler algorithms to this version and I don't know what else I can do to optimize it. I can't do it at smaller scale since the dimension of this matrix is firm. Do u have other idea to optimize?